# Looking for a simple, light xhtml editor (such as wmd etc.) for my site

Tags: xhtml

for now, i'm using WMD for my site, but lately i've been needing to work on its code, and the supplied code is near impossible to read, due to code obscurity (no tabs, var names such as _1, _2 etc). now, i assume that code has a non-obscured version, but its nowhere to be found. (for example, i need to be able to supply RTL support, and to fix some bugs)

i've found WYMeditor, but thats JQ, and my site works with Mootools (i know they can play nicely together, but thats loosing the light part)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack-overflow team reverse-engineered the WMD code back into non-obfuscated form to make changes; you should email them directly and ask about it - the link's at the bottom of every SO page.